# pandas getting key error when trying to pass variable

Tags: pandas, keyerror

I have a counter day = 0 and a string that concatenates to make a new column in a dataframe each time a loop is iterated.

The loop is initiated referencing a dataframe that already has a column titled day0. So this works with iterations I have constructed the variable as `fieldName = 'Day' + str(day)`

This seems to work because I don't get an error when passing the variable for a key in my first calculation in the loop:

```
df['Product] = df['E_pop'] * df[fieldName]
```

However, later in the code when I attempt:

```
df['div'] = df[fieldName] * .08
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Day0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 59, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Day0'
```

Why is the key recognized in my initial calculation but not my second?

Comment: There are two KeyErrors: `infCounts_D0` and `Day0`.

Comment: infCounts was in my original code. I modified the error message to match my generic post. I've corrected the error mesage.

Comment: Typo? `fieldName` vs `filedName` ?

Comment: @Vishnudev yes. Typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: Where are you creating `df[fieldName]` ?

Comment: @Vishnudev counter. day = 0, fieldName = 'Day' + str(day)

Comment: I figured it out. A join was causing an x and y appended to duplicate columns.